# Oracle Edition Based Redefiniton - promote to ORA$BASE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle version 19.20.0.0.0.

We are trying to test if the Edition Based Redefinition feature of Oracle will help us to remove the need for application outages when certain PLSQL objects are amended.

We have experimented with using `DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE` calls before executing PLSQL code but than does not work in all our scenarios.

So I have 2 schema - `the_user`and `the_coder`.

The `the_coder` contains PLSQL objects that `the_user` will execute.

So I enable `the_coder` for editions as follows:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY EDITION, DROP ANY EDITION TO the_coder;

ALTER USER the_coder ENABLE EDITIONS FORCE;
```

Then as `the_coder`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE the_pkg AS
   FUNCTION f RETURN VARCHAR2;
END the_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY the_pkg AS
   FUNCTION f RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN 
      RETURN ( 'Hello world' );
   END f;
END the_pkg;
/

GRANT EXECUTE ON the_pkg TO the_user;
```

As `the_user`:

```
SELECT the_coder.the_pkg.f FROM dual;

M
---------------------------------------
Hello world
```

The database has just the default edition `ORA$BASE`.

Now lets try some EBR, as `the_coder`:

```
CREATE EDITION ebr_poc;

GRANT USE ON EDITION ebr_poc TO the_user;

ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = ebr_poc;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE the_pkg AS
   FUNCTION f RETURN VARCHAR2;
END the_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY the_pkg AS
   FUNCTION f RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN 
      RETURN ( 'Hello world, again' );
   END f;
END the_pkg;
/

GRANT EXECUTE ON the_pkg TO the_user;
```

Then as `the_user`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = ebr_poc;
SELECT the_coder.the_pkg.f FROM dual;

M
---------------------------------------
Hello world, again
```

So how do I now 'promote' the changes from `ebr_poc` to `ORA$BASE` edition?

It seems with Editions, we would have to keep adding to editions, and know which one to make the default, but really we'd like to keep things as simple as possible and just move changes back to the `ORA$BASE` edition.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would just

```
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT EDITION = ebr_poc;
```

once you had confirmed that the code in the new edition was working correctly.  If you don't want to have a bunch of editions floating around in your system, you can drop the old edition once there are no longer any connections using it.

There is nothing special about `ORA$BASE` other than the fact that it is the only edition that exists when the new database is installed.  You can drop it like any other user-created edition when it is no longer needed.

In the [EBR FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/docs/tech/ebr-faq.pdf)

> Should a user drop ORA$BASE?

> It is necessary to drop the ORA$Base
> edition before other old, retired editions can be dropped. The
> ORA$Base edition is not special in any way other than that it is the
> name given to the one edition in the database when the database is
> first created. All our existing customers that have happily been using
> edition-based redefinition for many years all dropped the ORA$Base
> edition many years ago and have had no problems because of it.